# ReSharper, unused parameters and DbC, asserts, etc.?

Tags: resharper

If I have the following:

```
void Foo(Bar bar, Baz baz)
{
    // Do something with bar, but not with baz.
}
```

...then ReSharper warns me with "Parameter 'baz' is never used." and colours it grey. This is a useful hint that I might want to get rid of it.

On the other hand, if I have the following:

```
void Foo(Bar bar, Baz baz)
{
    Require.ArgumentNotNull(bar);
    Require.ArgumentNotNull(baz);

    // Some code that used to do something with bar and baz,
    // but has been changed to no longer use baz.
}
```

...then ReSharper thinks that 'baz' is used, and doesn't warn me. Is there a ReSharper annotation that I can use on ArgumentNotNull to tell ReSharper that this method doesn't really "use" the parameter, and to still issue the hint?

Comment: If the body of the method doesn't use baz, why do you require it to be not null? Semantically it's not hard to argue that requiring non-nullity *is* 'using' baz.

Comment: ...because it used to use baz, but doesn't any more; updated the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you annotate the "Require.ArgumentNotNull" method with [AssertionMethod] attribute (from ReSharper annotations library), then ReSharper will issue "Parameter is used only in precondition checks" warning.

Looks like that solves your problem.

Note: This is applicable to ReSharper 7.0, need to check how older version will deal with this.